# Test Class - Set LastLoginDate on test user

Tags: unit-test, user-management

Anybody know how to set the lastlogindate field on User for a test class?

Here is my scheduled apex class. I need to create a user with a lastlogindate more than 60 days ago in order to get 100% code coverage.

***Edited - working code***

```
   public class  sched_Freeze_60Day_Users implements Schedulable {

    @TestVisible static Date threshold = date.today().addDays(-60);

    //Make class schedulable    
    public void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {        

        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Chatter Only - External Client']; 

        //Find external users who have been inactive for sixty days.
        List<UserLogin> uLogins = [
            SELECT ID FROM UserLogin
            WHERE UserId IN (Select Id
                             FROM User 
                             WHERE LastLoginDate <= :threshold
                             AND ProfileId = :p.Id
                            )
            AND isFrozen = FALSE
        ];

        //Freeze any user accounts that were found. 
        if(uLogins.size()>0){
            for(UserLogin u:uLogins){
                u.IsFrozen = TRUE;
                    }

            update uLogins;            
        }

    } //end schedudle class
} //end main class
```

*** test class ***

```
@isTest
public class test_sched_freeze_60day_users {

    // CRON expression: midnight on March 15.
    // Because this is a test, job executes
    // immediately after Test.stopTest().
    public static String CRON_EXP = '0 0 0 15 3 ? 2022';


    @testSetup static void setupTestData(){

        //Create Testing Users
        User thisUser = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
        System.runAs (thisUser) {
            InsertTestUsers.InsertUsers();
        }

    }


    static testmethod void test() {

        sched_Freeze_60Day_Users.threshold = Date.today();

        Test.startTest();

        // Schedule the test job
        String jobId = System.schedule('ScheduleApexClassTest',
                                       CRON_EXP, 
                                       new sched_Freeze_60Day_Users());

        // Get the information from the CronTrigger API object
        CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, 
                          NextFireTime
                          FROM CronTrigger WHERE id = :jobId];

        // Verify the expressions are the same
        System.assertEquals(CRON_EXP, 
                            ct.CronExpression);

        // Verify the job has not run
        System.assertEquals(0, ct.TimesTriggered);

        // Verify the next time the job will run
        System.assertEquals('2022-03-15 00:00:00', 
                            String.valueOf(ct.NextFireTime));

        Test.stopTest();
    }        
}
```

Comment: Have you tried either of the methods suggested in [this help article](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000181873&language=en_US)?

Comment: @adrianlarsen  Adrian, your solution got deleted for some reason. I got enough of it however I think to get me on the right path.

Comment: I deleted it because I had my doubts. I can leave it here if you prefer that. I think finding a way to set the fields may be the right choice here though.

Comment: Could you update the code for this line ``InsertTestUsers.InsertUsers();``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend an alternative. Make your `sixtyDaysAgo` variable writable in a test context. Also, never use `global`. Usage of `public` should nearly always suffice unless you are working on a `Managed Package`.

```
public class MyScheduler
{
    @TestVisible static Date threshold = Date.today().addDays(-60);
    public static List<UserLogin> getUserLogins()
    {
        return [SELECT Id FROM UserLogin WHERE Id IN (
            SELECT Id FROM User WHERE LastLoginDate <= :threshold AND ...
        ];
    }
}
```

Your test class can then just set it to today.

```
static testMethod void testFindUser
{
    MyScheduler.threshold = Date.today();
    // run code
}
```

Comment: Ok, new code for me, are you saying that in my schedule apex class I can create a variable with the annotation of @testvisible?

Comment: That's what I'm saying, yep. And you can make a separate method dedicated to getting the `UserLogin` records. Although I'd think it might be null for users you create in your test. Might not work. Hmm...

Comment: I updated my original post with working code. I am getting 100% code coverage.